# Continuously check a JSON url for changes in data using Python

Tags: python, json, api, rest, web-scraping

I have a small script that I have written (see below) which fetches JSON data from a web url. The goal is to print out any new data in the JSON. Is there any way I can continuously check the URL every 5 seconds and report back any changes? I am sure I am not doing it right, but what i have tried is creating a first list from the JSON object items, waiting 5 seconds creating a second list and then comparing the two. This is obviously not the way to do it because I still have to run the script myself each time. I just want to run the script once have it kind of 'listen' or 'poll' the URL and throw back any changes in data. My code is below, any assistance is greatly appreciated and any other optimizations you would suggest for my script.

```
import json, requests 
import time

urls=["https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=false", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=false"]

def get_data(url):
    url = requests.get(url)
    text = url.text
    data = json.loads(text)
    coins = [coin['id'] for coin in data]
    return coins
 
def check_new_coins():
    first_list = get_data(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    second_list= get_data(url)
    new_coins = list(set(second_list).difference(first_list))

    if len(new_coins) > 0:
        for new_coin in new_coins:
            print(new_coin)
    else:
        print("No new coins")

for url in urls:
    check_new_coins()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're looking for

```py
import json, requests 
import time

class Checker:
    def __init__(self, urls, wait_time):
        self.wait_time = wait_time
        self.urls = urls
        self.coins = self.get_coins()
        self.main_loop()
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_data(url):
        url = requests.get(url)
        text = url.text
        data = json.loads(text)
        coins = [coin['id'] for coin in data]
        return coins
    
    def get_coins(self):
        coins = set()
        for url in self.urls:
            coins.update(Checker.get_data(url))
        return coins

    def check_new_coins(self):
        new_coins = self.get_coins()
        
        coins_diff = list(new_coins.difference(self.coins))
        
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        
        if len(coins_diff) > 0:
            print(current_time, coins_diff)
        else:
            print(current_time, "No new coins")

        self.coins = new_coins
    
    def main_loop(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.wait_time)
            self.check_new_coins()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls=[
        "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=false",
        "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=2&sparkline=false"
    ]

    Checker(urls, 5)
```

sample output:

```
18:57:20 No new coins
18:57:25 No new coins
18:57:30 No new coins
18:57:35 No new coins
18:57:41 No new coins
18:57:46 No new coins
18:57:51 No new coins
18:57:56 No new coins
```

Comment: This is great. How would i change it if instead of just getting `coin['id']` I also want to get `coin['symbol']` and `coin['market_cap']` from that same JSON? I tried using tuple, but it messed up `coin_diff` further down.